# jQuery-compatible timespan picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a javascript widget that will allow a user to specify a timespan, like "fifteen minutes" or "two weeks". I'm currently using jQuery and would like something compatible (as well as something open-source-friendly). While I've found plenty of time-oriented controls, they all seem to be for a time of day, possibly with an attached date, or a datetime range.

Are there any widgets out there allowing me to specify a length of time not attached to any specific dates?

Comment: Seems like a simple `<select>` would work, or are you after the ability for a user to type in the time span?

Comment: look for a calendar popup widget

Comment: specify based on what criteria? Predfined increments, or user defined? If predfined, what format do you need data in, and how does it need to be displayed to user. Really not clear what you are looking for or how it will be used. Likely easy to create...if know more about use case

Comment: here's one idea http://jsfiddle.net/EwEse/. Can easily be adapted for multiple use cases, depending on what you are trying to achieve